# Finding the M.V.U.E of n Bernoulli trials

Tags: self-study, binomial-distribution, unbiased-estimator, umvue

> Let $r$ be the observed number of successes in $n$ Bernoulli trials with probability $\pi$ of success. Then **M.V.U.E** (Minimum Variance Unbiased Estimator) of $\pi (1-\pi)$ is ?

$n$ Bernoulli trials can be considered to follow Binomial Distribution with parameters ($n$,$\pi$).

I understand that an efficient estimator of a parameter is always an **Uniform minimum Variance Unbiased Estimator**. And an unbiased estimator is called an efficient estimator if it satisfies **Cramer-Rao lower bound**.

So is finding the **Cramer-Rao lower bound** the way to solve this question? And if so how is it done because I am struggling in conjuring the **Likelihood Function**

**EDIT** : As mentioned by **@wuber** , I went through a few prevously answered questions([Maximum Likelihood Estimation for Bernoulli distribution](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/275380/maximum-likelihood-estimation-for-bernoulli-distribution)) pertaining to finding the **Maximum Likelihood Estimator** of $n$ Bernoulli Trials and this is what I got:

Let $x_{i}$ be the $i^{th}$ success such that   $r  = \sum_{i=1}^n x_i$

$$
\begin{align*}
L(\pi) &= \prod_{i=1}^n \pi^{x_i}(1-\pi)^{(1-x_i)}\\
\ell(p) &= \log{\pi}\sum_{i=1}^n x_i + \log{(1-\pi)}\sum_{i=1}^n (1-x_i)\\
\dfrac{\partial\ell(\pi)}{\partial \pi} &= \dfrac{\sum_{i=1}^n x_i}{\pi} - \dfrac{\sum_{i=1}^n (1-x_i)}{1-\pi} \overset{\text{set}}{=}0\\
\sum_{i=1}^n x_i - \pi\sum_{i=1}^n x_i &= \pi\sum_{i=1}^n (1-x_i)\\
\pi& = \dfrac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n x_i\\
\pi& = r/n\\
\dfrac{\partial^2 \ell(\pi)}{\partial \pi^2} &= \dfrac{-\sum_{i=1}^n x_i}{\pi^2} - \dfrac{\sum_{i=1}^n (1-x_i)}{(1-\pi)^2}
\end{align*}
$$

The **Maximum Likelihood** estimator of $\pi = \frac{r}{n}$

Therefore by *Invariance Property* $$ Estimator \ of \  \pi (1-\pi) = \frac{r}{n}(1-\frac{r}{n})$$

But back to the question at hand, can we deduce this as **M.V.U.E** ?

Comment: Your basic question--what is the Bernoulli likelihood--is answered many times here on CV.  Search https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=bernoulli+likelihood.

Comment: @wuber Thank you for pointing that out.

Comment: I have made an edit, let me know if it is correct.

Comment: This has been asked and answered before, like in https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/292255/119261, https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/143962/119261, https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/255250/119261, https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/410923/119261

Comment: @Xi'an Yes thats true. I am preparing for an examination and I've needed help in some areas. I hope I am not violating any rules.

Comment: The issue imho is more that, by repeatedly asking rather similar questions, you hint at the fact that the previous Q&A did not help you in the long run and at a deeper level than just solving the exercise.

Comment: @Xi'an I understand what you are saying. I'll keep that in mind in the future and not resort to asking similar questions.

Comment: Your course is apparently ignoring Bayesian statistics where estimators are downplayed in favor of deriving entire distributions for parameters we don't know.